# Voltage follower generates voltage by itself

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, capacitor, voltage-divider

I am currently working on a project that requires me to measure a capacitor voltage that can reach up to 250 V.

To measure such a high voltage I first created a voltage divider with very high resistor values so the capacitor doesn't discharge very fast (resistor1 = 10 MΩ, resistor2 = 200 kΩ). The problem is that with such high resistor values the Arduino doesn't measure the voltage exactly, since the max. resistor recommendation for the Arduino ADC is 10 kΩ.

I decided to wire an op-amp as a voltage follower to have lower impedance on the output, but the voltage follower doesn't measure capacitor voltages lower than 100 V (or 1.96 V after the divider) and what happens is that, when the voltage falls below that, the follower produces a small voltage by itself (around 1.9 V), thus tricking the Arduino into calculating the wrong voltage of the capacitor. The op-amp I'm using is the UA741 and I'm powering it with single rail supply.

Does anyone know why the voltage follower doesn't work?

Comment: The problem is that the output voltage of the single-supplied 741 cannot go below this value. If you still want the op-amp to be 741, you need to add a negative source with at least -2 V voltage (i.e. to make a split supply). The conventional solution is to use a rail-to-rail op-amp.

Comment: And why not use lower resistance resistors for the voltage divider, for example R1 = 100k and R2 = 2k? Take into account the power dissipated. The Arduino recommendations are about the equivalent input resistance (R1||R2).

Comment: [Reasons not to use a 741 op-amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp/304522#304522)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reasons not to use a 741 op-amp?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the 741 can't get closer to the rails than about 2 V, so with a single supply of, say, 0 and 12 V, the output would be limited to between about 2 and 10 V.

You could use a split supply, but it would be easier to use a rail-to-rail op-amp, and avoid the obsolete 741.

You could also try smaller voltage divider resistors.

BTW: The recommendation for the ADC is what it is, but the standard Arduino library for the ADC allows a *very* long time for the ADC to settle (which is why it is slow when you use the default settings), so you can get away with a higher impedance than the recommendation.